# Perl CGI::Session start issue

Tags: perl, session

When accessing script it creates or loads a session (and I print out the session ID for clarification of that).

However, when I visit the page the second time, the session_id changes such that on all subsequent page visits, the session ID remains that of the second visit.

What am I missing that would make the 1st session ID persistent?

Here's two blocks of code. I used the second to try to narrow the issue but it prevails.

```
my $session = CGI::Session->load(undef, undef, {Directory=>"$sessions_dir_location/sessions_storage/"}) or die CGI::Session->errstr();
 

    if ( $session->is_expired ) 
    {
    print $session->header(),
    $cgi->start_html(),
    $cgi->p("Your session timed out! Refresh the screen to start new session!"),
    $cgi->end_html();
    exit(0);
    }   


    if ( $session->is_empty() ) 
    {
    $session = new CGI::Session(undef, undef, {Directory=>"$sessions_dir_location/sessions_storage/"}) or die CGI::Session->errstr;
    }

my $session_id = $session->id();
print $session->header;
print qq(session_id=$session_id);
```

That has the issue as described and the next code, in isolation (without the conditional clauses and session checks) also demonstrates the issue.

```
$session = new CGI::Session(undef, undef, {Directory=>"$sessions_dir_location/sessions_storage/"}) or die CGI::Session->errstr;
```

Below is a list of the session data as dumped each visit by Data::Dumper.

1st time

```
using printqq(); session_id - 41da3faef2f8c84c8faf13480a33f0de

'_CLAIMED_ID' => undef,
               '_DATA' => {
                            '_SESSION_ID' => '41da3faef2f8c84c8faf13480a33f0de',
```

2nd visit:
using print qq(); session_id - 57035dc9f16de5402cd0700040c72ef4

```
'_CLAIMED_ID' => '41da3faef2f8c84c8faf13480a33f0de',
               '_DATA' => {
                            '_SESSION_ID' => '57035dc9f16de5402cd0700040c72ef4',
```

3rd visit

```
using printqq(); session_id - 57035dc9f16de5402cd0700040c72ef4

'_CLAIMED_ID' => '57035dc9f16de5402cd0700040c72ef4',
               '_DATA' => {
                            '_SESSION_ID' => '57035dc9f16de5402cd0700040c72ef4',
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to send the session id cookie back to the browser. The following works for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Session;

my $cgi = CGI->new();

# Data Source Name, defaults to "driver:file;serializer:default;id:md5"
my $dsn = undef;

# query object OR a string representing session id, defaults to CGI->new()
my $sid = $cgi;

# If you wish to specify a session directory, use the Directory option, which
#   denotes location of the directory where session ids are to be kept. If
#   Directory is not set, defaults to whatever File::Spec->tmpdir() returns,
#   see: CGI::Session::Driver::file for more information
my $session_dir = "/tmp/sessions";

# See CGI::Session::CookBook for more information
my $session = CGI::Session->load(
    $dsn,
    $sid,
    {
        Directory => $session_dir,
    }
) or die CGI::Session->errstr();

if ( $session->is_expired ) {
    print $cgi->header,
      $cgi->start_html(),
      $cgi->p("Your session timed out! Refresh the screen to start new session!"),
      $cgi->end_html();
    exit 0;
}

if ( $session->is_empty() ) {
    $session = CGI::Session->new() or die CGI::Session->errstr;
}

# CGI::Session will use this cookie to identify the user at his/her next request
#   and will be able to load his/her previously stored session data.
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id );
print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie);
# Alternatively use: See:
# https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/libcgi-session-perl/....
#    CGI::Session::Tutorial.3pm.en.html
#
#  print $session->header();
#


my $session_id = $session->id();
print $cgi->start_html(),
  qq(session_id=$session_id),
  $cgi->end_html();
```

Comment: Thank you. I look at that more closely. I was using the tutorial linked to from the cpan CGI::Sessions page.  Interested that you commented out print $session->header; Does't that send the cookie to the browser just like print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie);?